# How to enable button to be clicked for current and previous days but not for future ones?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently trying to have buttons that change the completion of a ToDo when clicked, but I only want to enable the button to be clicked for previous days and the current one.

For example, let's say that it is Wednesday, then I want my button to be enabled for Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday, but not for later days.

In my API I couldn't get the Days to be sent, just the id of the Day. So `Sun: 1 ... Sat:7`, and I can't think of a way to do that.

This is a code snippet for today being Sunday so the button should be enabled, but it is disabled for the rest of the days, it is just an idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

```js
<div key={day.id}>
  {habit.id === day.habitId && (
    <>
      {firstDay === "Sun" && day.id === 1 ?
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          {!day.isCompleted ? 
            <button type="submit" onClick={() => {setHandleChange([day.id, day.isCompleted]); setCompletion(!day.isCompleted)}}>[]</button>
            : <button style={{ color: habit.color }} type="submit" onClick={() => setHandleChange([day.id, day.isCompleted])}>[]</button>
          }
        </form>
        : <button disabled type="submit" onClick={(e) => {  setHandleChange([day.id, day.isCompleted]); setCompletion(e.target.value) }}>[]</button>
      }
    </>
  )}
</div>
```

`firstDay` is obtained by manipulating `new Date` so it is a dynamic variable. How can I make this idea dynamic, so that if the `day.id === 7` then all the buttons can be clicked, if `day.id === 1` then only the one for `Sun` can be clicked, if `day.id === 3` then `Sun, Mon and Tue` can be clicked but not the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep an array of day names, and then use [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) to get the index of "today". Then iterate over the days array, and if the current `map` index is greater than index of "today" disable the button.

```js
function Example() {

  const days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  const today = new Date().getDay();

  function handleClick(e) {
    const { dataset: { day } } = e.target;
    console.log(day);
  }

  function isDisabled(i) {
    return i > today;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {days.map((day, i) => {
        return (
          <button
            data-day={day}
            type="button"
            onClick={handleClick}
            disabled={isDisabled(i)}
          >{day}
          </button>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );

};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```